# Allow Steam game to accept incoming connections Mac

Tags: macos, network, firewall

So I am not really familiar with Mac, as I usually use Windows. I want to connect two instances of Stardew Valley (installed over Steam) using the LAN option.

- host computer uses macOS 13.6.3
- joining computer runs macOS 13.0.0
- The port used (by default) is UDP 24642
- [My guide is this one](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Multiplayer)

However, the connection does not happen. It seems from the joining side to be stuck trying to connect to the host.

I assume this has something to do with a firewall or something like this blocking the incoming traffic. I know the firewall is disabled on Mac by default and I double checked to make sure it is. I read that Mac OS usually manages the incoming traffic permissions quite well but maybe not for Steam apps. So does anyone know how I can allow Stardew Valley to receive incoming traffic?